# Get laravel response in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5

In my controller:

```
public function index(){
     $data = array(1,2,3,4,5);
     return view('index')->with(['data' => $data,]);
}
```

How can I access the `$data` in javascript inside index.blade.php?

In my javascript function I tried `JSON.parse(data)`. Also tried `this.responseData.data"` and `this.responseData.data`.

All gave me error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sales' of undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you return a view (blade view) in laravel with data you can access it using the following manner:

**Controller:**

```
public function index(){
     $data = array(1,2,3,4,5);
     return view('index')->with(['data' => $data,]);
}
```

**View:**

```
<body>
@foreach($data as $d)
{{$d}}<br/>
@endforeach
</body>
```

This will give you output in your browser like so:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

If assigning value to JavaScript the view should be:

```
<script>
    var data = [];
    @foreach($data as $d)
    data.push({{$d}})
    @endforeach
<script>
```

Now the variable data is an array which can be easily accessed in JS.

Comment: As I said, I need to get that data in javascript function, your answer is not appropriate.

Comment: @MASh are you using AJAX ?

Comment: Not now but may be later.

Comment: @MASh Ok so in that case the js approach of my answer shall resolve your problem.

Comment: If I use AJAX, what to do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140036/discussion-between-shakti-phartiyal-and-mash).

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think worth making a clarification. PHP is a server side language while javascript is a client side language. With that in mind, you can't directly access to a PHP variable directly from javascript.

There are two ways that you can access the data:

1. In your PHP write something like this: `<script> var data = $data </script>`. And then you can access the JS `data` variable in javascript.
2. Get the `data` with [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) (AKA AJAX). In this case you need to retorn a JSON from PHP